# Execute a Program Which Accept Command Line Parameters

Tags: c#

How to Execute a Program Which accepts Command Line Parameters in c#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5) method of the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0) class.

> Starts a process resource by specifying the name of an application and
>   a set of command-line arguments, and associates the resource with a
>   new Process component.

Example:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
```

Answer (score 6):

[ProcessStartInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)

> ProcessStartInfo is used together with the Process component. When
>   you start a process using the Process class, you have access to
>   process information in addition to that available when attaching to a
>   running process.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";
  Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();        
   startInfo.FileName = "C:\etc\Program Files\ProgramFolder\Program.exe";
   startInfo.Arguments = "C:\etc\desktop\file.spp C\etc\desktop\file.txt";
   Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Or you can try the link 
     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: is it a comment or what ? post the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(@"prg_name", @"args");
Process process = Process.Start(p);
```