# After running cmd command, need to enter account and password, then close it using C#

Tags: c#

I need to enter account and password in command line. How Can I achieve this? I'm using the following code.

```
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"/k" + Commmand;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
```

Below are the expected prompts resulting from the `cmd` process:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot write the account and password to continue the command

Comment: I think what you're asking is essentially answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530303/execute-a-program-which-accept-command-line-parameters).

Comment: Create a StreamWriter stream attached to `process.StandardInput` and [use `streamObj.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) maybe?  Your question is unclear.  Also, the `batch-file` tag doesn't seem relevant to this question.

Comment: Or maybe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308500/run-interactive-command-line-exe-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You must have a DB of "users", thant contains usernames and passwords. 
In command line ask from a user needed input and check it with you DB of passwords. DB can be anithing that is allowable in your case. For example simple List or smth like that.